# Why don't set Geometry column in OpenLayers wfs-t request to geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I want to edit a vector layer(its a point layer) using [OpenLayers 3.6](http://openlayers.org) and then save it with wfs protocol. I'm using [Goserver 2.8](http://geoserver.org/) in server side. I define my layer as follow:

```
var u="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=opengeo:Point";
format = new ol.format.WFS({});
wfs = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Point',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(u),
        format: format
    })
});
```

I get all features correctly. Now I add a point to layer as follow:

```
point = new ol.geom.Point([39.8274942, 21.4226638]);
feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: point
});
feature.set('NAME', 'Ya Ali Madad');
source.addFeature(feature);
```

Now saving feature is as bellow:

```
node = format.writeTransaction([feature],null,null,{
    featureNS: 'http://opengeo.org',
      featureType: 'opengeo:Point',
      srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
});

s = new XMLSerializer();

var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs";

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
    method: 'POST',
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(node),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log("All thing is right.");
    }
});
```

I use Extjs-6 for creating ajax request. it create a request as follow:

**Request Payload**:

```
<Transaction 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
    service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
        http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <Insert>
        <opengeo:Point xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org">
            <geometry xmlns="http://opengeo.org">
                <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <pos>39.8274942 21.4226638</pos>
                </Point>
            </geometry>
            <NAME xmlns="http://opengeo.org">Ya Ali Madad</NAME>
        </opengeo:Point>
    </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

**Request in Network**:
[image]

And geoserver response this request as follow.
**GeoServer response**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:TransactionResponse 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
    xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org" 
    xmlns:usa="http://census.gov" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    version="1.1.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
        http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">

    <wfs:TransactionSummary>
        <wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted>
        <wfs:totalUpdated>0</wfs:totalUpdated>
        <wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted>
    </wfs:TransactionSummary>
    <wfs:TransactionResults/>

    <wfs:InsertResults>
        <wfs:Feature>
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="new0"/>
        </wfs:Feature>
    </wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

Geoserver **add this point in database**, **but don't set geometry field**. it only set properties column and Not geometry column.

**Where is the problem**? ***How can I do to fix it?***

Comment: What is the output of DescribeFeatureType on your typename? Is your geometry even called geometry in the feature model?

Comment: sorry I don't undrstand you

Comment: This is a DescribeFeatureType request: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeaturetype&typename=topp:states It shows you the schema. In this case the geometry column is named as "the_geom". Check your own feature type.

Comment: This part or insert request defines that the geometry column is named as "geometry" but it should be "the_geom" `<geometry xmlns="http://opengeo.org">` Perhaps you should edit this part of your javascript `feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: point
});` I am not sure, though, but you must make the name of the geometry column to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Insert` request contains an feature that doesn't match your Schema which is expecting the Point attribute to be called `the_geom`. You don't get an error because you have marked that feature as Nillable (or optional).

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://opengeo.org">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PointType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AREA" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERIMETER" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IR_CEN_" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IR_CEN_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="X_COORD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Y_COORD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Point" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="opengeo:PointType"/>
```

If you change your request to the following it should work - the best way to test this is using the demo requests page in GeoServer.

```
<Transaction 
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
    http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<Insert>
    <opengeo:Point xmlns:opengeo="http://opengeo.org">
        <the_geom xmlns="http://opengeo.org">
            <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                <pos>39.8274942 21.4226638</pos>
            </Point>
        </the_geom>
        <NAME xmlns="http://opengeo.org">Ya Ali Madad</NAME>
    </opengeo:Point>
</Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Now you must define the feature as follow:

```
feature = new ol.Feature({
    the_geom: point
});
```

And then set `geometryName` features config:

```
feature.setGeometryName('the_geom');
```

Comment: Yes I do it correctly. But how do I do in my code?`feature.setGeometryName('the_geom');` It don't work correctly.

Comment: Where you say geometry point try the_geom point

Comment: I brought All of code that I used for defining **layer, **adding feature** and **sending insert request** to server.

Comment: here: feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: point
});
should be: feature = new ol.Feature({
    the_geom: point
});

Comment: change to `feature = new ol.Feature({ the_geom: point });`? Does not work properly.

Comment: Actually rereading the docs it looks like you should use feature.setGeometryName("the_geom"); if that doesn't work then it looks like a OL3 bug - you probably need a new question